# Parsing an array of ojects into strings in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am calling `Get-AdComputer` like this:

```
[string[]] $computer = Get-ADComputer -properties * -filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*")} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"} |
    Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate
```

This creates a string array and I can access it like this:

```
$computer[1]
```

which returns

```
@{Name=W7-9HQPR3J; LastLogonDate=05/08/2017 09:45:13}
```

I need to output the data to a csv file in two columns `Name, LastLogonDate`

Unfortunately when I call `$Computer | out-file -filepath $ServiceTagsPath -Force -Width 200 -Encoding ascii`

I get one column with the headings on each line:
[image]

My other requirement is to be able to use the Name column in web-service calls to get warranty information...

so how could I do that?

Comment: Sign up for the Dell TechDirect API, there's one for Warranty, using these will be much easier than scraping the values from an HTML page. You can request the info you want in a format that powershell can deal with natively: https://techdirect.dell.com/portal.30/AboutAPIs.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not cast the output to array of strings `[string[]]` but leave the casting to powershell. 
Then you can use command `Export-Csv` which works better with array of objects.

```
$computer = Get-ADComputer -properties * -filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*")} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"} |
    Select-Object Name, LastLogonDate

 $computer | Export-Csv "test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: this outputs a csv with `#TYPE System.String` as the heading and all records are just the number *53*

Comment: I think you have copied the code from @Shawn Esterman or try to flush the variable by Remove-Variable or simply close and open shell window again

Comment: @OurManinBananas note that `[string[]]` has been removed in this answer.

Comment: @pandemic: no, I took that out... and set the `$computer` variable to $null